# Pointing to another Procedure variable

Tags: delphi

What i'm looking for is to use a procedure variable with another procedure using pointers.

Example:

```
Procedure Test1;
var
Word:String;
begin
Form1.Caption:=Word;
end;

Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
^Word:='Form1';
Test1;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify another procedure's local variable before it even exists. In your example, just use an input parameter instead:

```pascal
Procedure Test1(const Word: string);
begin
  Form1.Caption := Word;
end;

Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Test1('Form1');
end;
```

Otherwise, add a member to the `TForm1` class instead:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  public
    Word: string;
    ...
  end;

...

Procedure Test1;
begin
  Form1.Caption := Form1.Word;
end;

Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Word := 'Form1';
  Test1;
end;
```